# Cannot assign to value: 'k' is a 'let' constant

Tags: swift, function

I am solving a problem and , i have to decrease the value of `k` which is a parameter in a function , but when i am decreasing the value of k it says `Cannot assign to value: 'k' is a 'let' constant`
Here is the code

```
var count:Int = 0
func maximumToys(prices: [Int], k: Int) {
for i in prices {
    if i < k {
        k = k - i
    }
} }
```

Comment: yeah K is immutable so how can i make it mutable?

Comment: Create a local variable in your function and return a result from your function, instead of trying to manipulate an external variable passed in from the outside.

Comment: Problem is your code makes no sense. Why are you changing k? What is count for? What are you really trying to do? Are you trying to find max/min in an array? That is not how to do it. Be more informative! Thanks

Comment: it's a greedy problem so for every i < prices , i need to decrease the value of k .

Comment: But you need to STATE the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **inout** keyword. Try this:

```
func maximumToys(prices: [Int], k: inout Int) {
    for i in prices {
        if i < k {
            k = k - i
        }
    }
}
```

An example usage:

```
    var prices = [Int]()
    prices.append(1)
    prices.append(2)
    var k = 4;
    maximumToys(prices: prices, k: &k)
```

Comment: Why use `inout` over a simple return value?

Comment: This is a solution. The return value is another solution. If maybe he does not want to use a return value.

Comment: The solution of using the `inout` works, but I advise against it. It makes the flow of information hard to follow. Better to copy k to a local variable and rewrite your function to return the changed local variable.

Comment: I do not agree with you. inout keyword is useful in some cases. It is like pointers especially when you do not want to create a new variable and copy it to the return value.

Comment: Also apple says:

As an optimization, when the argument is a value stored at a physical address in memory, the same memory location is used both inside and outside the function body. The optimized behavior is known as call by reference; it satisfies all of the requirements of the copy-in copy-out model while removing the overhead of copying. Do not depend on the behavioral differences between copy-in copy-out and call by reference.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift, variables in functions are by default constants and *copies* of the original value (assuming they're structs, as is the case with `Int`s).

There are two ways around this:

You can either declare a variable copy within the body of the function, and then you can return k:

```
func maximumToys(prices: [Int], k: Int) -> Int {
  var k = k
  ...
  return k
}
```

Or you can use the `inout` keyword on the variable. If you use the `inout` keyword, be aware that you are going to be modifying the original value. This makes your code no longer thread safe, as multiple accesses of the same memory path can lead to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

if the variable is coming from parameter just use `inout` keyword before variable name like this

```
func convertToBytes(bytesToSave : inout [UInt64])
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you cannot update a value of ‘k’

Just use a temp variable

```
var count:Int = 0
func maximumToys(prices: [Int], k: Int) -> Int {
var j = k //temp variable 
for i in prices {
    if i < j {
        J = j - i
    }
}
return j
}


let result = maximumToys(prices: [10,20], k: 30)
```